# UITextView with autolayout is wordwrapping too soon

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextview, autolayout

I'm trying to set up a UITextView with autolayout rules inside a UICollectionViewCell.

I have constraints on the leading and trailing side of it, such that:
Leading is greater than or equal to 1:8 the screen's width and trailing is equal to the screen's width minus 15px.

This work well and achieves my desired behavior (keeping the text view as small as possible until it exceeds my maximum line length, then it will wordwrap) most of the time. However, for certain strings/string lengths it screws up and truncates way too early.

An example:
If I set the UITextView's text to: "http://www.billywitchdoctor.com" it all prints out on one line no problem.

However, if I set it to just: www.billywitchdoctor.com the "m" gets knocked off to the next line somehow, so it renders like:

```
www.billywitchdoctor.co
m
```

even though there is plenty of space left for the bubble to stretch width-wise. I've tried setting the Compression Resistance Priority to 1000 for the UITextView and reducing hugging but I can't seem to do anything to remove this issue so long as I have these two constraints on the bubble (leading >= 1:8 cell trailing and trailing == cell trailing.)

I know I can probably programmatically fix this issue for each cell by calculating and specifying the width myself, but I'd rather use auto layout if possible.

Comment: Why do you have the leading constraint? Did you want your text to be right aligned?

Comment: Think of it like a chat bubble in messages. Text is in a chat bubble, chat bubble's width is defined by the text's width, chat bubble is right-aligned but text is left-aligned within the chat bubble.

Comment: You may need to call `layoutIfNeeded` on your text view whenever the text changes.

Comment: One convenient locations. In Africa.

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidating the layout whenever the text changes.

```
- (IBAction)textViewDidChange:(UITextView*)textView {
    [textView invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}
```

Comment: Right now, it happens regardless of whether I change the text or even set it to anything other than what's in the storyboard

Comment: Did you try using this delegate method?

Comment: Ya, I implemented it in the ViewController and set the textview's delegate, but it doesn't get called.